# Better way to detect if isIpad?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I have an universal app that changes the screen layout based on what device the user has.
It seems to work pretty good, but I've had one user call in (and send me screen shots) of his iPhone 4 showing him the iPad view instead of the iPhone view. I haven't been able to duplicate it on any of the phones we have around here, but I'm wondering if there there is a better way to do this since iOS 4.3 has come out.

```
+(BOOL)isIpad{
  return ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
}
```

Alternately, is there just a way to detect screen size? I mostly use this to determine how wide elements in a table should be, but if Apple comes out with iPad 3 with retina display, it would be nice to have the app just adjust everything accordingly.
Also useful if the app is in portrait or landscape. Make it so that it just anchors to the edges like elements in WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When loading XIBs for a universal app this, or what you're already doing, seems to be the only way:

```
NSString *xibName = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)?@"SomeView~iPad":@"SomeView";
```

As for screen size this should work:

```
CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Comment: I'll give the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() method a try. I have to do an update anyway, so it works out. Plus, once the user gets the update I'll know he's on the current version.

Comment: Missing `[` in `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];` I tried to edit it in there but Stackoverflow is nowadays insisting edits must be at least six characters. Last time I waste time trying to edit something.

Comment: @MaxHowell Fixed the edit... Looks like you need more reputation in order to edit a post with less than six characters.

Answer (score 1):

This is like a bazillion years old, but came across it in google so I figured I'd post a poorly documented but very useful feature. If you add ~ipad to the end of the filename for your iPad specific nib it will automatically load that one instead. Same logic as @2x for loading images. So your iPhone nib would be named myview.xib and your ipad myview~ipad.xib and iOS will correctly load the ipad version wherever needed. Fancy!

Answer (score 1):

UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad is now deprecated. The new way to do it would be using TraitCollections. It can only be called on Views.

```
-(BOOL) isiPad{
    return self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular && self.view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular;
}
```

Refer Apple Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitCollection_ClassReference/)

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's good to keep the information current, and I hadn't seen the documentation on the TraitCollections method yet.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it has a previous version of the app and conflict with the new!

Try to remove old one and reinstall new! It works! I already encountered this issue.